# using svn log to extract commit messages between tags when revisions overlap across branches

Tags: svn, version-control, commit, revision

I always use the svn log command, e.g.`svn log -rXXXX:YYYY` to get the commit messages between two tags in my SVN repository.

The problem I sometimes find is that if I am doing a large release that includes releasing a tag froma branch that has never been released to that environment before I can have problems extracting an accurate list of commit messages.

For example, I wish to release the difference between 01.02.03 (r4152) and 01.03.02 (r4272), now a normal `svn log -r4152:4272` may look like the obvious answer here, but the `02.03` branch has never been released before (to this environment anyway), so I note that 01.03.01 has a revision of **4126** which pre-dates the tag 01.02.03.

So I am releasing code from the `01.03` branch from the first time, so I need to be able to extract the revision messages for everything applicable under this branch and not just the numerical revision differences.

Is there a way to do this with the `svn log` command?

Comment: could you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I 100% understand your request, however below is something to consider if you haven't yet.

Below uses the `log` command you referenced form different locations, to try to get you what you desire. This of course depends on your SVN directory structure, so it may or may not help depending on how you have your setup.

For example if your SVN repo looks like:

```
 /someproject
    /devbranch
    /01.02.03release
    /01.03.02release
    /somethingneverused
```

If you then map `/someproject` to a local folder, you should then be able to go to that folder through the command line and run the `svn log -r4152:4272` command from that directory and its subdirectories. Only the items that are at the level or below will be shown in the log.

If this isn't enough to give you what you want, then you might be able to use some logic to pull all the logs from `/someproject` followed by running a script to remove logs from `/someproject/somethingneverused`